# How to hide label associated with disclosure button in picker displayed in form

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-environment

i have a picker in form which is enclosed in Navigation View. The Picker item displays disclosure button with label text in it.

[image]

Is there any way we can hide the label that is associated with disclosure button?. For example in the above image i want hide Rome label.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't hide the selected value. But you can use `NavigationLink` as a work-around:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var input = ""
    @State private var active = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                NavigationLink("What is your favourite city?", isActive: $active) {
                    List {
                        Button("Rome") {
                            input = "Rome"
                            active = false
                        }
                        Button("Paris") {
                            input = "Paris"
                            active = false
                        }
                        Button("Berlin") {
                            input = "Berlin"
                            active = false
                        }
                        Button("New York") {
                            input = "New York"
                            active = false
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```